# Removing smell from leather Apple Watch band?

Tags: apple-watch

I have a "Classic Buckle" style leather band for my Apple Watch.  After having it for about two months now, the band has really begun to stink due to moisture and sweat!

Has anyone found a good way to clean the band and manage the smell?  I have done a simple wipe down like Apple recommends, and also taken it off for longer periods to dry out, but that hasn't really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is just a normal leather watch band if you remove it from the apple watch, I suggest following the same cleaning directions as normal analog watch owners use.
a quick google search yielded this result: [ebay watch band cleaning guide](http://www.ebay.com/gds/Your-Guide-to-Cleaning-Leather-Watch-Straps-/10000000178722470/g.html)

Comment: why the downvote? I use this method on my watchbands and they still look and smell fine